# Why is $\mathbb{Q}_\infty = \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Why, in the context of p-adic numbers, do we have the convention
$$\mathbb{Q}_\infty = \mathbb{R} \quad$$
?

It must have something to do with the generalization of the Legendre-symbol for $\mathbb{R}$:
$$\left(\frac{\cdot}{\infty}\right) = \mathrm{sgn}(x)\, ,$$
but why does "$\infty$" make sense here?

Comment: No, $p=\infty$ is not a prime number. The absolute value $\mid.\mid_{\infty}$ is the Euclidean one, in contrast to the $p$-adic value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The archimedean absolute value is denoted $|\cdot|_\infty$ for notational conveniency, so one can write for instance
$$
\prod_{p\leq\infty}|q|_p=1\qquad\forall q\in\Bbb Q, q\neq0.
$$
Thus, as $\Bbb Q_p$ denotes the completion of $\Bbb Q$ with respect to $|\cdot|_p$, it is more than natural to denote $\Bbb Q_\infty$ the completion of $\Bbb Q$ with respect to $|\cdot|_\infty$.